# Not able to print the key and values in twig files

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am not able to get the key and values in for loop
My requirement should be like the 
Title - description

I am not able to get the value in title and description

```
                       (

                        [product_benefit] => Array(
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                [title] => Ipsum Lorem 
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                [title] => Ipsum Lorem 
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                [title] => Ipsum Lorem
                            )
                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                [title] => Entertainment
                            )
                    )


                     {% if product.product_benefit is not null %}
  <ul class="manual-list">
    {% for row in product.product_benefit %}
        {% for slug, item in row %}
                <li><b>{{ item.title - item.description }}</b></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Comment: not working boss
<li><b>{{ item }}</b></li> enable to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue you have is that your output is now substracting two strings, either switch to `{{ foo }} - {{ bar}}`or `{{ foo ~'-'~ bar }}`

For reading out the data:

- If you want to use the `keys` directly in your code then your 2nd `for` is obsolete.

```
{% for row in product.product_description %}
    {{ row.title }} - {{ row.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

- If you want to keep the keys dynamic you'd need the 2nd for loop but you don't use the literals anymore

```
{% for row in product.product_description %}
    {% for key, value in row %}
        {{ key }} = {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/3g45wa)

Comment: Thank you, the second one solved my problem. Is there any link to it in the [Twig docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/), or should we add it ?

Comment: This [section](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys) covers how to iterate keys and values